# Прохождение объекта через 2D коллайдер без остановки

Tags: unity3d

Мне нужно реализовать механику, при которой пуля, соприкасающаяся с первым коллайдером первого врага, не остановится, а полетит дальше и выключится только при соприкосновении со вторым коллайдером второго врага. Я ввёл условную int переменную и присвоил ей значение 2. При каждом соприкосновении с коллайдером врага, от числа вычитается единица. Единственная проблема, что пуля, при соприкосновении с первым коллайдером бьётся об него и отлетает, а должна продолжать лететь(проходить сквозь коллайдер, при этом засчитываться).

Comment: Использовать триггер на пуле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутрь объекта пули поместите пустой gameobject и задайте у него коллайдер, как триггер. Затем проверяйте столкновения через этот коллайдер. (На объекте пули коллайдера не должно быть)

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо!

Comment: @NikitaMatskevitch Замечательно, не забудь пожалуйста отменить ответ, как верный.